# Merge list of results into a single variable with Python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, matplotlib

The development that I have to do in Python consists of taking an xml file with the tree built from the sig. shape:

[image: diagram]

Xml file example:[I put here xml file becuase of big it is](https://github.com/MR/blob/master/example.xml)

The last tag (Signal) as seen in the image above in green is from which I have to extract the values ​​of the Name and Value attributes; this can be repeated at the same level two or more times with different values ​​in these attributes.

The functions that read the xml would be the following:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import pandas as pd
    
    file_xml = ET.parse('ejemplo.xml')
    print("File: ", rootXML)
    rootXML= file_xml.getroot()
    
    def fragmentXML(rootXML):
       for child1 in root:
          for child2 in child1:
             for child3 in child2:
                for child4 in child3:
                    for child5 in child4:
                       for child6 in child5:
                           for child7 in child6:
                               levelChild7(child7)

             transformData(values)
```

When taking the data with Pandas, putting it into a dataframe and grouping the data, I group them one by one and not all at once; this is the function I am using to group them and paint them in a graph with Matplotlib:

```
     def transformData(data_final):
        df_dataXML.groupby('Name')['Name'].count().plot(kind='bar')
        plot.show()
```

This is the console result of this last function, which brings me all the data separately and obviously the graphs too:

[image: graph 1]

**The problem is that I do not know if there is any way to join the attributes (Name and Value) of Signal to pass them to Pandas in the Dataframe and I graph everything together with names and values ​​in the graph. And I did not graph each name and value separately as in the last image.**

I have tried with lists, tuples and dictionaries but I cannot unite the values, as if the label were a single entity and thus it was painted, separately.

Next I share a failed attempt with lists by changing the levelChild7 and transformData function:

```
    def levelChild7(child):
       nameSignal = []
       valueSignal = []
       if child7.tag == 'chid7_e':
          for child8 in child7:
             for child9 in child8:
             print(child9.tag)
       elif child7.tag == 'chid7_f':
          for child8 in child7:
             for child9 in child8:
                print(child9.tag)
       elif child7.tag == 'chid7_p':
          for child8 in child7:
             for child9 in child8:
                print(child9.tag)
       else:
          for child8 in child7:
             nameSignal.append(Signal.attrib['Name'])
             prevValueSignal = Signal.attrib['Value']
             splitValueSignal = prevValueSignal.split(' ')
             valueSignal1st = splitValueSignal[0]
             valueSignal.append(int(valueSignal1st))
             values = nameSignal+valueSignal
             #print(values) 

             transformData(values)

    def transformData(data_final):
       df_dataXML = pd.DataFrame(data_final)
       print(df_dataXML)
```

The result is this below, which is the Name and Value attribute as something that I cannot find how to group, since they are separated by rows and by each tag that it finds in the XML document:

[image: result]

**Could someone guide me to know how to regroup the values ​​of Name and Values ​​and put them in a single variable? Or tell me what is missing from my code?
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Please post sample of XML in body of post for a [mcve] and not as [screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451).

Comment: Done @Parfait edit my question and put an example of the xml. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply parse to needed `<Signal>` nodes which can be handled in list/dict comprehension passed into `pandas.DataFrame` constructor:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

file_xml = ET.parse("Input.xml")

data = [
    {"Name": signal.attrib["Name"],
     "Value": signal.attrib["Value"]
    } for signal in file_xml.findall(".//Signal")
]

signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

signals_df
#            Name             Value
# 0        Status             4 Run
# 1   PhysicalRes       0 0,1 1,2 2
# 2        Status             4 Run
# 3        Status             1 Off
# 4     GlblClkYr    0 2000,21 2021
# 5        BrkTot        8191 Fault
# 6           ACU  0 FrontRequester
# 7           ACU           7 Radio
# 8           ACU  0 FrontRequester
# 9           ACU         4 Granted
# 10   GlblClkDay           1 1-3 3

signals_df.groupby(["Name"]).count()
#              Value
# Name
# ACU              4
# BrkTot           1
# GlblClkDay       1
# GlblClkYr        1
# PhysicalRes      1
# Status           3
```

Should you need all attributes of `<Signal>`, simply return the `attrib` dictionary:

```py
data = [signal.attrib for signal in file_xml.findall(".//Signal")]

signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

signals_df
#        Error    Hexval         Name             Value
# 0   {x:Null}     0,1,2       Status             4 Run
# 1   {x:Null}     0,1,2  PhysicalRes       0 0,1 1,2 2
# 2   {x:Null}      0,15       Status             4 Run
# 3   {x:Null}      0,15       Status             1 Off
# 4   {x:Null}      0,15    GlblClkYr    0 2000,21 2021
# 5   {x:Null}      1FFF       BrkTot        8191 Fault
# 6   {x:Null}  {x:Null}          ACU  0 FrontRequester
# 7   {x:Null}  {x:Null}          ACU           7 Radio
# 8   {x:Null}  {x:Null}          ACU  0 FrontRequester
# 9   {x:Null}  {x:Null}          ACU         4 Granted
# 10  {x:Null}         1   GlblClkDay           1 1-3 3
```

And in forthcoming [Pandas v1.3](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#contributors), there is now a direct handler for [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) which by default returns all attributes and child elements:

```py
signals_df = pd.read_xml("Input.xml", xpath=".//Signal")
```

---

Once all data is compiled, run plotting as needed:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

signals_df.groupby(["Name"]).count().plot(kind='bar', rot=0)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Parfait, it really helped me understand how I had to use ElementTree's findall() method... it's good to know about the version of Pandas v1.3, I still have 1.1.5... all your explanation helped me a lot!!!... My answer below...

Comment: Ok, thanks... I posted another question related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823936/plot-graph-with-vertical-labels-on-the-x-axis-matplotlib