# Plot graph with vertical labels on the x-axis Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

To continue my research on how to plot a xml file and continue checking my code, I first applied a division to `signal.attrib ["Value"]`, since it shows some string values ​​and what I'm interested in is the numeric values.

And as you can see below, I relied on the documentation for [Pandas and SQL Compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#compare-with-sql).

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot

def transformData (rootXML):
  print ("File:", rootXML)
  file_xml = ET.parse (rootXML)
  data_XML = [
      {"Name": signal.attrib ["Name"],
        # "Value": signal.attrib ["Value"]
        "Value": int (signal.attrib ["Value"].split(' ')[0])
        } for the signal in file_xml.findall (".//Signal")
  ]

  signals_df = pd.DataFrame (XML_data)

  signals_df [(signals_df ["Name"] == 'Status') |
              (signals_df ["Name"] == 'Lock_Stat')]. plot (kind = 'line', rot = 0)
  plot.title ('Changing signals every time they occur')
  plot.xlabel ('Signal name')
  plot.ylabel ('Signal value')
  plot.show ()
  plot.clf ()
  plot.close ()
```

I ran it with a complete xml file with lots of signals like the one found in [this link](https://github.com/MR/blob/master/example.xml): (I'm putting it here because it does not allow me to attach the code due to the length of the xml)

So once I compiled all the data, I ran the chart diagram and it comes out like this (Not all labels are in the file):

[image]

Actually what I have to use is something like the "switchpoint trace" graph near the bottom of [this page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jdwittenauer/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/libraries/PyMC.ipynb). But for now I'm working on it and it serves me in a graph of lines.

**But how to divide it on the x-axis by the names of the labels ('Name') instead of the numbers 0,20,40 etc, i.e. how to make all the names appear on the graph and put them vertically? Is it possible to do this? Or I don't know... Could Matplotlib convert the labels to numbers and then paint the description of the numbers next to the labels next to the graph to make the graph more understandable?**

Comment: `df _ Signals`? `Split('')`? Please fix syntax and space issues to be compilable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line plots in pandas use the DataFrame or Series index by default. Consider setting the index to `Name` prior to plotting. Also, use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for needed filtering by multiple values:

```py
names_list = [
   'Status', 'SetDSP', 'HMI', 'Delay', 'AutoConfigO_Rear', 'AutoConfigO_Front', 
   'AutoConfigO_Drvr', 'AutoConfigO_Allst', 'RUResReqstStat', 'RUReqstrSystem', 
   'RUSource', 'DSP', 'CurrTUBand', 'DrStatDrv',  'PW_Chim', 'BtnID', 'Cod_BtnID', 
   'SetVol', 'Lock_Stat'
]

(signals_df[signals_df["Name"].isin(names_list)]
   .set_index("Name")
   .plot(kind="line", rot=0)
)
```

Or with [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
(signals_df.query("Name == @names_list")
           .set_index("Name")
           .plot(kind="line", rot=0)
)
```

Alternatively, use `x` argument of [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```py
(signals_df[signals_df["Name"].isin(names_list)]
    .plot(kind="line", x="Name", rot=0)
)
```

However, `set_index` may raise an error and `x` argument may return undesired results if `Name` repeat in data more than once. Therefore, like your previous post, consider running `groupby` to aggregate *Value* per each unique *Name*. Below averages values for each name:

```py
signals_df.groupby(["Name"])["Value"].mean().plot(kind="line", rot=0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Parfait, this was the answer that helped me. Is there any way, method, or plot attribute for all the Name tags to appear on the graph? and not as it appears in the image: [link](https://github.com/MarshRangel/Python/blob/master/graph.png)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, with xticks().

```
# Your labels list
labels = [chr(x) for x in range(65, 91)]
# > ["A", "B", "C" ..., "Z"]  as an example
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(26, 1) # random data to illustrate

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xticks(ticks=range(len(data)), labels=labels, rotation=90)
plt.plot(data) # Your data
plt.show()
```

[image: Example of plot with rotated xticks]

Notice that, most of the time, when you want to get fancier with your plot, you'll want to manipulate the figure and the axe more precisely and with more available parameters .

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(range(len(data)))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
ax.plot(data)
plt.show()
# Same result
```